# $G$ has at most one subgroup of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ a group, $H$ and $K$ two subgroups of G of finite order such that $H \cap K = \{1_G\}$.

I already show the first exercise which says that the cardinal of $HK$ is $|H||K|$.

The second exercise ask to deduce that if $|G|=pm$ where $p$ is a prime number and $p>m$, then $G$ has at most one subgroup of order $p$. Show that if the subgroup exist, it is normal in $G$.

I think a can use the Cauchy and Sylow theorem, but I'm a bit block off on this problem. Is anyone is able to give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for sophistication. If $G$ has two distinct subgroups of order $p$ then those subgroups satisfy the conditions on $H$ and $K.$

Now since the subgroup is the only one of its order, it is identical to all of its conjugates and therefore normal.

Comment: There is some subtle sophistication: you must use $p > m$: $|H||K|=p^2 \leq |G|=pm$ , which cannot be the case.

Comment: I meant: no need for named theorems. The condition $p>m,$ as you correctly note, is necessary to conclude that $H\cap K=\{1_G\}.$

Answer (score 1):

First notice that if $p>m$, $p \nmid m$. So the $p$-Sylows of $G$ will have order $p$. The Sylow theorems tell you that the number of $p$-Sylows is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ and is also a divisor of $m$. Using the fact that $p>m$, what are/is the possible number(s) of $p$-Sylows? Now consider conjugates of the $p$-Sylows to show normality.